# ElasticSearch issue with querying a multi-valued property

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm running into an issue in that I have a document indexed with elasticsearch and when I query against a multi-valued field, it returns no results.  Here is my search:

> curl -X GET
>   "http://mncoboss13:9200/boss_model_reservations/_search?pretty=true"
>   -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":[{"terms":{"day_plan":["MO"]}}]},"size":100,"from":0}'

Results in:

> {  "took" : 2,  "timed_out" : false,  "_shards" : {
>       "total" : 5,
>       "successful" : 5,
>       "failed" : 0   },   "hits" : {
>       "total" : 0,
>       "max_score" : null,
>       "hits" : [ ]   } }

Here is the way I've indexed the document (notice that day_plan is an array of strings).  Notice that even in the example below, it has a day_plan with MO within it; however, given the above search, is not returned.  Am I doing something wrong with my filter?

> **http://mncoboss13:9200/boss_model_reservations/_search?pretty=true&q=*&size=1**

```
{
        "took" : 2,
        "timed_out" : false,
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 5,
          "successful" : 5,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "hits" : {
          "total" : 27493,
          "max_score" : 1.0,
          "hits" : [ {
            "_index" : "boss_model_reservations",
            "_type" : "boss_model_reservation",
            "_id" : "779588",
            "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"name":"","upccode":"701592001542","publish":true,"reservation_type":"class","time_start":37200.0,"time_end":39000.0,"date_start":"2012-07-19","date_end":"2012-07-30","day_plan":["MO","TU","WE","TH"]}
          } ]
        }
      }
```

UPDATE: The Type mapping for this index is here:

```
{
  "boss_model_reservations" : {
    "boss_model_reservation" : {
      "properties" : {
        "date_end" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "date_start" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "day_plan" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "format_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "interest_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "option1" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "option2" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "option3" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "product_line_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "product_type" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "publish" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "reservation_type" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "resource" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "resource_type" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "time_end" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "time_start" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "upccode" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the type mapping for "boss_model_reservation"? The term filter assumes the field "day_plan" is not analyzed.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the index mapping.  It is stating it as a type : "string"

Comment: curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/boss_model_reservations/boss_model_reservation/_mapping' -d '{
    "boss_model_reservation" : {
        "properties" : {
            "day_plan" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
    }
}'

Comment: The mapping needs to show "day_plan" : {
  "type" : "string",
  "index" : "not_analyzed"
}, then the term filter works.

Comment: OK that worked great.  Thanks so much.  Is the not_analyzed index because of the multi-valued field?  For example, if I had a multi-valued field of longs, would I need to do the same for that?

Comment: analyzed is the default for string fields, but the term filter expects a not_analyzed field. So I don't think this has anything to do with multi-values.